# using an auth token with an event

Tags: django, token

An issue I am having is determining how to create a security token associated with a page that will secure the page and hold information about the visitor.  I'd prefer to hash the function instead of encrypt because this will be faster.  What is the optimal method so I can send a url like:

```
/event/1?token=239874dsjakl.jf82374hanfan
```

where the token will have information in it related to the person clicking the link and the event?  Is this a good use for salts or would encryption/decryption be worthwhile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table to store the information associated with a generated token:

```
class AuthToken(models.Model):
    token = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    used = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # add additional fields as you need to store information about the token
    # event = models.ForeignKey....
```

To generate a random cryptographically secure token, use `os.urandom()`. Something like this will work:

```
binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(32)).decode('utf-8') # 64 character string
```

Then you can use the token in a URL. e.g.

```
/event/1?token=0c5a2774537834e870c2dbab1059eb7358fee7da879e0f14748a35414082ea24
```